# How to skip blank window during loading while UIPageViewController loads its first VC?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, launch-screen

My app load cycle shows the `LaunchScreen.StoryBoard` VC, but then for a second or two it displays the blank `window` before it displays the first VC in my `UIPageViewController` which is ugly UI.  Is there a way I can show the `LaunchScreen` over the window (i.e. is there a method on `window` I can set in my `appDelegate`) so it seemly transitions from `Launchscreen` to the first VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me with this...because the content that I was displaying in my `UIPageViewController's` VC's was derived via an asynchronous thread (`NSXMLParser`)...this delay time was what was interrupting my UI and displaying the window prior to the first VC.

I simply copied and pasted my `LaunchScreen.StoryBoard` into my Storyboard as a separate VC (and subclassed and added a storyboard ID), then in my `UIPageViewController` I loaded this new VC in `viewDidLoad` until my async call from `NSXMLParser` came back and displayed my first VC.